# Bootstrap Navbar with uneven vertical elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, vertical-alignment

`https://codepen.io/bencasalino/pen/NWPLLYQ`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-0 color-white" href="#"> 
          Logout |
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-0 color-white" href="#"> 
          Logged in as: 
          <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-5.jpg" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0"
            alt="avatar image" height="35">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

On the right side of the navbar I have two elements with the same classes that aren't being vertically aligned. I'm struggling with why they would be doing this if they have the same style and tag type.

Specifically looking at the Logout and Logged in as text. Codepen added for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this CSS where we're occupying the complete height available by the li and then align the `<a>`:

```
.navbar-collapse ul li a{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

**working snippet** below:

```css
/* Default Styles */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Navbar Styles */

.navbar {
  background: rgb(0, 101, 163);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 101, 163, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 167, 229, 1) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.cta-logout {
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  /* background-color: white; */
}

.cta-logout:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
}


/* ZAPP Color Style Guide Presets */


/* Black */

.color-black {
  color: #444444;
}


/* White */

.color-white {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* Grey-1 */

.color-grey-1 {
  color: #A6ADB4;
}


/* Grey-2 */

.color-grey-2 {
  color: #BBBDC0;
}


/* Blue-1 */

.color-blue-1 {
  color: #BBBDC0;
}


/* Blue-2 */

.color-blue-2 {
  color: #305C89;
}


/* Blue-3 */

.color-blue-3 {
  color: #004976;
}


/* Blue-4 */

.color-blue-4 {
  color: #27A9DE;
}


/* Blue-5 */

.color-blue-4 {
  color: #80A4BA;
}


/* Orange */

.color-orange {
  color: #EE7411;
}


/* Yellow */

.color-yellow {
  color: #F7AD41;
}


/* Lime */

.color-lime {
  color: #8AC340;
}


/* Green-Success */

.color-green {
  color: #148137;
}


/* Red-Error */

.color-red {
  color: #E92228;
}

.navbar-collapse ul li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">

<!--Navbar -->
<nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <img src="/images/zapp-logo-white.png" width="100" height="50" class="d-inline-block " alt="">
    <img src="/images/zapp-onsite-logo.png" width="60" height="50" class="d-inline-block " alt="">
  </form>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-0 color-white" href="#"> 
          Logout |
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-0 color-white" href="#"> 
          Test |
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-0 color-white" href="#"> 
          Logged in as: 
          <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-5.jpg" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0"
            alt="avatar image" height="35">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<p></p>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```